# Tutorial or example for zookeeper C binding

Tags: c++, c, apache-zookeeper

I am trying to create an application that uses the zookeeper C/C++ api. I would like to get a few examples on how they are used. I perused through the [official documentation](http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.1.2/zookeeperProgrammers.html#C+Binding), but a lot of details are missing, many sections are listed as TODOs. I looked through the code examples, but there are hardly any comments, which makes it difficult to understand what's going on. Could anybody help with some documentation specifically for creating C bindings?

FYI: I checked the usual channels, google, official documentation etc.

Answer (score 3):

Zookeeper client C binding are pretty close to Java bindings. So you can use
http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.3.4/api/index.html
to familiarize with concepts.
Also this page http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.3.4/zookeeperProgrammers.html
contains general description with several examples in C.

But I am afraid there aren't much C bindings specific docs out there. I was in the same situation some time ago myself. I was forced to read source code to answer all my questions.