# How to connect to zookeeper server from different machine?

Tags: c, apache-zookeeper

My code, which is written in C for the [C Client binding for zookeeper](http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/current/zookeeperProgrammers.html), runs perfectly on my local computer using the same ip (not localhost:2181). However, compiling and executing my code on another computer yields with a connection loss error. I was not able to connect to my zookeeper server by using my public IP(I got my publicIP by looking up whatsmyip on google). I did an ifconfig on my terminal to get the 10.111.129.199. I am assuming this is a private IP as it starts with 10. The machine I have ssh'd to is running SolarisOS. This caused me to change a single function in zookeeper source code from synch_fetch_and_add (I think) to atomic_add because sync_fetch... is not supported by SolarisOS. According to ZooKeeper documentation, [SolarisOS is not currently supported](http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/current/zookeeperAdmin.html) by Zookeeper. I am able to compile Zookeeper perfectly fine, and am told someone else in my company had implemented Zookeeper beforehand on our systems.

My program is trying to create a single node on the zookeeper server. My code looks like this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    //zh is a global zookeeper_handle for now.
    zh = zookeeper_init(host_port, my_watcher_func, 20000, 0, NULL, 0);
    if(zh == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error connecting to ZooKeeper Server!! \n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        return 0;
    }
    int retval = create("/TFS/pool" , "1");
    printf("return value of create = %d\n", retval);
}

 int create(char* path, char* data){
    int value_length= -1;
    if(data != NULL){
        value_length = (int) strlen(data);
    }
    printf("creating node at path: %s with data %s\n", path, data);
    int retval = zoo_create( zh, path, data, value_length,
                            &ZOO_OPEN_ACL_UNSAFE, 0, 0, 0);
    return retval;
}
/*empty watcher function*/
//I have no idea why this is needed. 
void my_watcher_func(zhandle_t *zzh, int type, int state,
                 const char *path, void *watcherCtx) {}
```

Both systems are running GCC compiler. The problem, I think, isn't in the code as it runs fine locally, but the connection issue I am facing.
I would assume that zh would return 0 if the connection to the zookeeper was a failure from the zookeeper_init() function. This however does not happen and continues to the create().

```
creating node at path: /TFS/pool with data abc

2018-07-16 
10:30:44,232:16332(0x2):ZOO_ERROR@handle_socket_error_msg@1670: Socket 
[10.111.129.190:2181] zk retcode=-4, errno=0(Error 0): connect() call 
failed 

return value of create = -4
```

When I telnet to the ip:port it will connect. I also know that zookeeper detects my connection during telnet because I am running it in the foreground. The following is the output of zkServer.sh running in foreground when I connect via telnet 10.111.129.190 2181

```
2018-07-16 11:04:03,807 [myid:] - INFO  
[NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxnFactory@215] - 
Accepted socket connection from /10.7.1.70:61479
```

The expected output should have been:

```
creating node at path: /TFS/pool with data 1

2018-07-16 12:14:37,078:3180(0x70000c98c000):ZOO_INFO@check_events@1764: initiated connection to server [10.111.129.190:10101]
2018-07-16 12:14:37,107:3180(0x70000c98c000):ZOO_INFO@check_events@1811: session establishment complete on server [10.111.129.190:10101], sessionId=0x10000590d2b0000, negotiated timeout=20000

return value of create = 0
```

This output has always confused me as zookeeper connection is established after the zookeeper_handle is initiated. It is established upon zoo_create() instead of zookeeper_init. Doesn't effect anything, but just an interesting time to establish a connection.

I understand that retcode=-4 means CONNECTIONLOSS, but it's not even able to establish a connection with the server. If there is anyway I could fix this please do tell!.

Comment: Take the [tour], read [Ask], and [MCVE]. You applied the C tag and I don't see any C code in your post. Do both machines have the same architecture? It could be you've got an [endianess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) problem, but you didn't post an MCVE, compiler version/invocation, or any information about the two systems arch/OS.

Comment: Ok I will read through those links and change question to provide more complete information

Comment: At the end of the main function.  retval = create();

Comment: Have you seen _[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11573538/tutorial-or-example-for-zookeeper-c-binding)_ on the topic?

Comment: Yes. Those zookeeper documentations helped me get this far.

Comment: What does the person in your company who _implemented Zookeeper beforehand on our systems_ have to say?

Comment: How have you implemented _my_watcher_func()_?  (others will ask, you should probably post it)

Comment: Just for grins and giggles, can you try your code using `localhost:port` to see what happens?

Comment: localhost:port gives the same error. my_watchur_func () has been added to the question. Thanks for your input. I have also emailed the previous person, I am hoping he can help.